# Binding to UserControl property with casting

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have list of `UserControls` which is binded to `ItemsSource` of of my `TreeView`. In `TabControl.ItemTemplate` I have to bind to Property of my custom `UserControl`.

I have tried everything, but nothing worked for me.

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderTitle"></TextBlock>
     ...
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

My UserControl:

```
public partial class FullTextSearchResult : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }
    private string _headerTitle;
    public string HeaderTitle
    {
        get { return _headerTitle; }
        set
        {
            _headerTitle = value;
            HandlePropertyChanged("HeaderTitle");
        }
    }

    public FullTextSearchResult(ViewModelBase model)
    {
        HeaderTitle = (model as FullTextSearchResultViewModel).Model.HeaderTitle;

        InitializeComponent();

        #region ViewModel configuration

        ViewModel = model;
        DataContext = ViewModel;

        #endregion
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void HandlePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do it? I have tried also Converters, but maybe in incorrect way.

Best regards.

Comment: It is not clear what you are wanting to do here? Are you trying to provide a search facility for the TreeView? As a start you should look into `DependencyProperty` class.

Comment: I only need to BIND to string Property . To `HeaderTitle` in my `Textbox`.

Comment: It is unclear where the TabControl is. Is it part of your UserControl?

Comment: Yes it is, but I need to Bind to UserControls which are in ItemsSource  of TreeView.

Comment: So you have UserControls, a TreeView and a TabControl. It's impossible to see how these are related. Please provide more details in your question.

Comment: As Clemens said there's no way to tell without seeing more, but binding a collection of explicitly declared controls is usually a code smell. If you instead bind a collection of data and apply bound UserControls to those items in a template, then you can more easily pass around the raw data to use elsewhere.

Comment: @John Bowen, I've done that before, and need to change that, because of handling creation of Views (parametrized constructor - too low .NET version, to get x:Arguments). But I've solved this problem, using VisualTreeHelper.

Comment: And sorry, I was thinking about `TabControl` but I wrote `TreeView`